# Implenting local storage for each request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, instrumentation

I am Instrument node.js application, for these I need to find out which method belongs to which request, so for these I have maintained unique id for each request, but where should I store this id so that it is accessible for all methods and it should be separate for each request. I need something like thread-local concept of java in nodejs,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)

It's pretty easy to use

```
var NodeCache = require('NodeCache');
var myCache = new NodeCache();
var obj = {'some': 'object'};
myCache.set('key', obj);
var cached = myCache.get('key');
```

It won't work if you have a Node Cluster I believe. In that case you'll have to use an external system like Redis.

Of course, Javascript objects themselves can be used as associative arrays:

```
var associativeArray = {};
associativeArray.foo = 'bar';
associativeArray['bar'] = associativeArray['foo'];
```

Comment: For every request i need to get set separate Id and later in methods I need to used them but, Here with node cache or assocative arrays if second request came while first request serving then it will override previous inserted id

Comment: You could have the ID map to a list of the methods, and when the second request comes while serving the first request just append the method(s)? for the second request to that list.

Another way would be to have a key that would be the ID + some way of differentiating which request it is (a counter, time, or some other uniquely identifying thing)

Comment: how can I map each request with associated method, method doesn't have any relationship between request

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you're trying to say. If there's no relationship between methods and requests, then how can you map in between them? Both Javascript objects and things like Node-Cache should give you enough direction in how to save mappings, but if you're asking how to create a mapping system that's something you'll have to figure out yourself.